# display content of selected list item after some interval of time

Tags: android, listview, onitemselectedlistener

i want my app to show the details/data of list items at the side of the list view.

OnItemSelectedListener would change the details/data every time I scroll for each list item.

I want those contents of list item to be changed after I stopped scrolling from DPAD and waited some seconds.

How can I do that.

Comment: And from which of the many visible list items the details should be shown?

Comment: @greenapps the selected item if is selected for some fixed interval of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working with the thread had solved the problem, restart the thread on each item selection. The thread sleeps for some interval and then populates the data.

Answer (score 2):

Implement an onScrollListener and start a timer when the scrolling stops. In the timer task set details.

Comment: I think it could help me but If I got some more idea on it about how to use it'd be of great help

Comment: Start with implementing a listener. In on scroll just retrieve the position and display somewhere (in text view or title of activity). Did you ever do something with a timer and timer task? Then look for examples on this site and play with them. Realise that it is easy for me to say "start a timer when the scrolling stops" but that that is tricky to implement. As you actually have to start a timer when the scrolling starts.

Comment: Very nice. Actually I found your problem so interesting that I just implemented it myself and was about to post the results. But this is better...

Answer (score 1):

On the activity with the listview, you need to add the following code:

```
@Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String ID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid))
                            .getText().toString();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                            EventDetails.class);
                    intent.putExtra(pid, ID);
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
```

Then on the new activity showing the details, you need to add the following:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
pid = i.getStringExtra(COL_PID);
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting this answer if it has helped you :)

Comment: It will not have helped as the user is not clicking a view to begin with.

Comment: @michele click event is used to open new intent I am doing so in the same activity here so its not helping but thanks for your response